# if auto_update_statistics is made ON by using sp_autostats for a particular index of a table will Statistics for every DML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, statistics, dml

I hit upon **auto_update_statistics** on google, it suggest if we make this ON we do not need to update **Statistics**, SQL Server will do it.

I was wondering so for any Insert, Update(of Indexed Column), Delete on Table will result in Update of **Statistics**? If yes will not that create latency for transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistics do not get updated along with the insert/update/delete operations themselves. These operations just update a modification counter so SQL Server can keep track of how many changes there have been and whether an update is due.

When a query is executed that would use the statistics SQL Server checks whether the statistics are stale and updates the statistics if required.

The definitive article on the subject is [Plan Caching in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (from which this flow chart is taken)

[image]

As mentioned earlier SQL Server maintains a count of the number of modifications made to each column. If the number of modifications since the plan was compiled exceeds the recompilation threshold (RT) then the plan will be recompiled and statistics updated. The RT depends on table type and size.

> RT is calculated as follows. (n refers to a table's cardinality when a query plan is compiled.)
>
> **Permanent table** 
>   -  If n <= 500, RT = 500. 
>   -  If n > 500, RT = 500 + 0.20 * n.
>
> **Temporary table** 
>   -   If n < 6, RT = 6. 
>   -   If 6 <= n <= 500, RT = 500. 
>   -   If n > 500, RT = 500 + 0.20 * n. 
>   **Table variable** 
>   -   RT does not exist. Therefore, recompilations do not happen because of changes in  cardinalities of table variables.

These recompilation thresholds are not suitable for all situations. e.g. see [Statistics, row estimations and the ascending date column](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/) and [traceflag 2371](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saponsqlserver/archive/2011/09/07/changes-to-automatic-update-statistics-in-sql-server-traceflag-2371.aspx) can be used to modify the behaviour.

If `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` is `OFF` then the statistics are updated by the requesting spid before compilation can continue. If this option is `ON` then the statistics are updated by a system spid in the background and the original query is not blocked but just continues using the stale statistics.

One additional way in which statistics can be updated is that rebuilding an index will also update the statistics with `FULLSCAN` at the same time.